# How can I return focus to a page after pressing Alt in Microsoft Edge?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-edge

In most programs, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> by itself will open and focus on the title menu. Pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> or pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> again will then return focus to wherever it was before pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

In Microsoft Edge, pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> by itself will focus on the three dots menu button without opening it (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> focuses on and opens the menu). Unfortunately neither <kbd>ESC</kbd> nor a subsequent pressing of <kbd>ALT</kbd> will return focus to the webpage. Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> moves focus in to the next UI element, not to the part of the page that previously had focus, e.g. a text field halfway down a page.

After pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd> in Edge, is there any way to return focus to the last element that had it, ideally with a single keypress or combination? (I'm encountering this behavior while programming in a Jupyter notebook, so moving over to the mouse is an appreciable disruption of my workflow.)

I am using Chromium Edge, version 92.0.902.55, 64-bit.

Comment: @Ramhound That's a great question. I'll add detail to my post.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Chromium Edge version 92.0.902.55. Additionally, pressing TAB after ALT brings the focus to the next row after the three dot menu. This might be the top of your page, but for me it's the bookmarks bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments I experience the same issue.
Through trial and error I found that pressing <kbd>F10</kbd> brings the focus back to the page, at the location you were before pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd>.

[Apparantly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/keyboard-shortcuts-in-microsoft-edge-50d3edab-30d9-c7e4-21ce-37fe2713cfad) that's the key to:

> Set focus on the Settings and more "…" button